# Secondary API call within Django Server Failed but working for external API

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, python-requests

I have to call an API endpoint from another API endpoint within a Django Project. 
This is like:

`http://<IP>:<PORT>/primaryendpoint/`
=> this is mapped to one Class Based View (`class getPrimaryendpoint`)

which will do another API call in the same server i.e.

it will call `http://<IP>:<PORT>/secondaryendpoint/`

For this I'm using `requests`, creating session to call from `primaryendpoint` to `secondaryendpoint`.

**When using 3rd party URL endpoint instead of `http://<IP>:<PORT>/secondaryendpoint/`, it's working fine( i.e. from primary endpoint we are able to call 3rd party URL EP which is outside of our Django Project ) but for this internal call (within Django project) it's throwing error :

`Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)`

Note: This was working fine in Windows but failing in Linux system.
      Using: 
      `Django 1.11, Django REST Framework, Python 3.6`

`Bottom-line question:`
How to make an internal API call from another API call in Django?

Comment: If you want help with an exception you'll need to provide the full traceback.

Comment: How to make an internal API call from another API call in Django?

Comment: As of now I can't provide the traceback.

Comment: Without a traceback it's impossible to guess what's going on. Maybe there is no value at line 1 column 0 (char 0)?

Comment: Where does the error occur - in `requests` when it tries to make the HTTP request? Do you have a traceback?